# what should I be careful of when buying a new motherboard for an old computer?

Tags: repair

I got a broken computer from my friend, after diagnosis, the motherboard is dead.

The owner want to replace the motherboard with a new one, but his computer was bought 5 years before.

What should I consider for the motherboard to fit the other parts of the computer?
As far as I know, the hard-disk is an IDE. We need a motherboard with on-board display. Should we care about the model/brand of the old cpu? Are there any other things that should be considered?

Answer (score 1):

agree w/ Moab.  for some reason, obsolete motherboards aren't any cheaper than the new ones.  1 more thing; Even if you get a motherboard with the same socket, there's not guarantee that a older motherboard will support a newer CPU.(even with the same socket...it happened to me!)

I just checked. you can buy a brand new CPU for $29.  (newegg)  There are advantages to buying new stuff that you can send back the store.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a Dell or other company brand PC, it is very difficult to retrofit aftermarket boards into these, you are better off buying a new computer case and motherboard, reuse what hardware you can from the old one, which won't be much, maybe the optical drive if the new motherboard has ide, which most do not these days.

It may be cheaper to buy a new PC on sale than build your own.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an old PC that isn't particularly high spec, you could consider putting in an integrated board like the Intel D510MO, D410PT or similar. The older system you have may have DDR2 memory you can use.

Bear in mind, these systems are generally integrated with the non-replaceable, entry specification Intel Atom processor. Check on-line at various sources to ensure the specification of the replacement board with integrated processor is suitable. Also they are generally very limited expansion-wise and will not typically have PCI-Express or AGP slots.

The main benefit however is these boards are integrated with very mature, tried and tested chipsets and are very cheap to buy compared to motherboard and processor separately, and in a lot of cases, a great drop-in replacement for slightly older PCs that need replacement boards.

Answer (score 0):

You should always check which processor it had(until your not deciding to sale the old one). If you are attempting to upgrade observe the following things,

```
 1. Processor
 2. RAM type
```

The rest of the things are mostly compatible with all. If you have an old processor and RAM, I suggest that you sale the things and buy a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have touched on the need to make sure the computer uses a standard architecture.

The problem with buying a new motherboard for an old computer is that you'll pretty much have to buy new RAM and a new CPU to go with it.  THrow in a new hard drive if you can't find a board that supports IDE, and you're very quickly looking at close to $200 or more.

If you are looking for an inexpensive way to replace a dead motherboard, buying a used motherboard on Ebay may be the way to go.

You can easily find used but fully functional obsolete boards there for around half the cost of a new motherboard, and if you are comfortable and familiar with assembling computers from parts, finding a used good-quality motherboard that is compatible with the dead computer's RAM and CPU will give you a working system for much less than the cost of a new motherboard + new CPU + new RAM, etc.

Just be careful to only buy from sellers who guarantee the board will work, and stick with a brand name board (Intel, Gigabyte, etc).